# IE10: Script5007: Object expected Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

IE10: Script5007: Object expected Error

This is for tabs on my product page: 
http://www.amleo.com/new!-arborrain-hydrator-for-trees-and-plants/p/VP-AR/

Just started experiencing this, but only in IE10

```
    $(function(){

        $('#tabs li').click(function(){
            var index = $(this).index() +1;
            $('#tabs, #tabs-content').children().removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('#tab' + index).addClass('active');
        });
        PersonalizationClick(document.getElementById("personalization"));
    });
```

Comment: Try to add something like "http:" to the start or the script's `src` attribute where them start with "//". I guess I remember having some problem like that in the past.

Comment: I'm not seeing a SRC attribute...I'm just seeing tab, tabs, etc.

Comment: Which line *exactly* is throwing the Object Expected exception? Which object isn't assigned?

Comment: I just run the debug window of IE9 (not 10, sorry) and it looks like the `$` identifier is not defined and when look at the scripts loaded in the page head I noticed some sources (`src`s) defined as "//some_path..." including jQuery, my suggestion is change them to "http://some_path...".